# IIS Issue? Site not coming up all of a sudden

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

So I have a site setup on a server. It has been working for ever. All of a sudden it stops working. I tried going to it even by IP. It just says, "Under Construction..

Under Construction

The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. It may be in the process of being upgraded and configured..."

I check to make sure it was pointing at the right virtual dir and that the default page was set in the documents list. The default page does exist in the dir too....

Nothing has been changed via code. Nothing has been altered on the server. I have a bunch of other sites running on the same server and they are all coming up. Just wondering if there was something that may have happened or overlooked. Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks a million.

Comment: So as I was messing with it more... I stopped the website name 'Default Web Site' Now when I try to go to it by IP it says 'Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)' Does this help narrow the problem down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we rebooted the server and now it works again. I guess I should have tried that in the first place. It was just odd that all the otehr sites were working. Anyway thanks for suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your bindings are set correctly. Perhaps a new site was created which conflicts with the bindings of your site?

**Edit**

Make sure .net is set to the right version. I've seen where pages are not served up when the web is set to 1.1 on a 2.0 site.

Also does the site work locally on the box? Have you ruled out firewall issues / changes or other network related elements.

Comment: I made sure that no other site was binded to the same IP. There hasnt been any new site created either. hmmmmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your request is being handled by another IIS site.  Make sure that the host header is set correctly.

---

With your comment, the "Bad Request" error means that the default web site was handling the request.  There are a couple of things you can check:

1. If this is not the site that you expected to serve your app, then you still have a website identity issue.
2. If your app is hosted on the default web site, then make sure that the default document is set correctly.
3. Also make sure that you don't have a file named "app_offline.htm" in your app's root.

Comment: The host header is set correctly. But even if it wasnt shouldnt it still come up by IP ?

Comment: David means you must use a correct host header in requests. Simply using IP may still lead you to another site.